# Create new AutoField using migration

Tags: python, django

From collegues I inherited multiple identical MySQL databases. Using DJANGO's inspectdb I derived the data models for it, and created a web interface to view the data. When instantiating the model structure again, DJANGO failed to create a unique_together contraint for 2 fields.

**Problem**:
I want to get rid of the existing unique_together and the 2 primary keys, as DJANGO does not support mutiple primary keys. For example with the DJANGO auto generated id field (as primary key). Is this possible, and how should I do it? Writing a custom migration would be an option, but how?

**Contraints**
Data loss is not an option, so I cannot just drop tables. 
Also the migration history should be maintained.

*What I have is*:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  sessionid = models.ForeignKey('Session', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sessionID', primary_key=True) 
  datetime = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)

  class Meta:       
      unique_together = (('sessionid', 'datetime'),)
```

*But it should become something like*:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  sessionid = models.ForeignKey('Session', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sessionID') 
  datetime = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

When removing the prmimary keys, DJANGO attempts to create the desired id autofield. However, as data exists in the table, DJANGO requires default initial values for this. Though a default value is not allowed, as the primary key (autofields are primary keys) must be unique.

Comment: `unique_together` is not a primary key! Also it is called composite primary key, not multiple primary key.

Comment: You're right, I corrected it.

Comment: After introspecting the database with `inspectdb` are the models now managed or unmanaged? If they are managed, it means you'd like to change the models and add the changes through migrations. In that case your approach should work, but please keep `unique_together`, it is important for validation. If you run `makemigrations` an `AutoField` with the name `id` should be created.

Answer (score 1):

It's 3 years late, but I hope that it will help someone. When you remove primary_key attr in all your model fields, Django will try to create an AutoField field named **id**, which will be the primary_key of your model, but when you already have data in the DB, you must set a default value for existing entries which will cause another issue because primary_key is **unique**.
But a solution can be to create manually an **primary_key** field named **id** in your SQL table.

1. Remove the current primary key

`ALTER TABLE tablename DROP PRIMARY KEY;`

2. Create a new primary key field

`ALTER TABLE tablename ADD id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;`

If you want that Django takes this field as default primary key, you must set its name as **id**.

3. Make migrations on you django app.

Delete all your migrations files in the corresponding app and re-run `python manage.py makemigrations`. Your code must be like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  sessionid = models.ForeignKey('Session', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='sessionID') 
  datetime = models.BigIntegerField()

  ...
```